# IE 9 getWindowHandles - Does not identify new browser window

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.32, IEDriverServer 2.32, Eclipse, Java JDK 1.6.0_43 with Windows 7 and IE9. The code that i use to launch the driver is

```
File file = new File("IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
DesiredCapabilities ieCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
ieCapabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);
```

In IE9, When i click on a link which opens a new browser, the driver.getWindowHandles() returns only one browser (Parent browser) and the new browser is never identified. When i use the same code with IE 8, it works and it identifies the new browser.

Due to company policy, the 'Security' settings are different for different zones in IE9. For two zones, the 'Enable Protected Mode' is enabled and while in other zones, the mode is not enabled. Is this the reason for the issue?. Please suggest.

Comment: Its an usual one. After clicking on the element, I have put an wait of 8 seconds and the new browser gets loaded well within those 8 seconds and then I am using 
    System.out.println(driver.getWindowHandles().Size());
The above code returns 1 instead of 2.

Comment: The Protected Mode settings could very well be the issue. Have you (or more importantly, the short-sighted control freaks who don't let you set this basic harmless setting on your machine) read the [definitive explanation](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.com/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html) describing _why_ those changes are necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Steps are as below:

1. 'Enable Protected Mode' should be checked for all the zones and
   security level should be set to "Medium".
2. Give some time to load the page using Thread.sleep(). Now you will
   get correct value for getWindowHandles() method.